# Accessing ArrayList in Javascript - ASP.Net MVC2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, arraylist

I have ArrayList in my Model and want to iterate through it in javascript. I am using following code but its giving me error :  CS0103: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

```
for(var i=0; i <= <%=Model.KeyList.Count%>; i++)
{
    alert('<%=Model.KeyList[i]%>');      
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. The c# code is executed at the server side before the javascript code is executed therefore the variable i doesn't exist when you execute the c# code. I can't really tell you how to fix it as you don't say what you want to do. But you ether need to iterate the list server side in a c# loop, or client side in a js loop. You can't mix them together.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't work. The foreach is evaluated at client and the <% ... %> instructions are evaluated at server. For that reason "i" doesn't exists, it only exists on the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JS to parse the list, you need to convert it to a javascript array.  The final result you need to produce is this a collection of objects in { } notation (as in `{ name: "a", value: "b" }`) and wrapped with [].

So you need to generate this client code and parse it on the client, or scrap it and process it on the server.  Or, create an action result that returns a JsonResult and return the array; the MVC framework should auto convert for you; you'd have to request that with JavaScript via AJAX.

HTH.